# Native OpenGL in winforms panel in WPF

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, winforms, opengl

In my project, I already have a native C++ library wrapped in C++\CLI, then referenced in my WPF application. Within my application, I have an aqua-colored Winforms panel displayed:

```
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="openGLWF">
            <winForms:Panel x:Name="openGLPanel1"
                    Dock="Fill" 
                    BackColor="Aqua" Paint="Panel_Paint" />
        </WindowsFormsHost>
```

What I'm trying to do is have the panel to be used to draw my OpenGL content from my native library. I've search around and through books that hints that it is possible, but the "solutions" I've found are not thorough and are too ambiguous to implement.

**NOTE:**
*After being flagged by user **gbjbaanb** of a possible duplicate that was answered **5 years ago,** my issue is different as the "original" that he referenced deals with .NET 4.0 and Winforms, where I'm dealing with .NET 4.5.2 and WPF with a Winforms panel inside of it.*

Comment: @gbjbaanb So how is this a duplicate? Please explain

Comment: @gbjbaanb You might want to look at the difference between that and mine. I'm not working in Winforms. I'm working in WPF that has a winform's panel. Not the same thing.

Comment: The solution is the same. You have to get the hwnd from the WinForms panel and construct the OpenGL context on it. There is no difference whether the control is located in a WPF WindowsFormsHost or directly in a WinForms application.

Comment: @BDL That's an ambiguous comment and doesn't clarify anything. That's the equivalent of saying "To drive a car, you turn the key, then push the gas" and just walking away without really explaining how it is to be done. You just parroted generalizations and really didn't offer a viable solution. And if you looked at the source code to the duplicate, you will see the difference.

Comment: @gbjbaanb Why did you hide your comments from the page? user script?

Answer (score 1):

The workflow is basically the same as with every windows control or window. The only difference is, that one does not have to construct the hwnd since this is already done by the WinForms control. So a example for creating an OpenGL context on a Windows-Forms control could looks like this (C++/CLI):

```
public void InitGL(System::Windows::Forms::UserControl^ userControl)
{
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)userControl->Handle.ToPointer();
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

    //From now on everything is similar to initializing a context on any other hdc
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |
          PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 24;
    int iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(hdc, iFormat, &pfd);

    HGLRC hrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);

    //From now on we have a valid OpenGL context
    //Do other stuff like glewInit etc. now
}
```

Note, that this code is similar to the one [here](http://zolver.blogspot.co.at/2012/06/opengl-rendering-control-under-managed.html), which was already linked in the duplicate answer suggestion.

Comment: The overall problem is how to link a window to the panel (openGLPanel1). Even the source code to the link doesn't provide relate-able information.

Comment: And a related page that I've seen many pages reference from the MSDN site no longer exists

Comment: You don't have to link a window to the panel. The panel replaces the window. On a lower level, windows and panels are the same thing (both represented by their hwnd).

Comment: I found a quite simpler way that was staring in my face. I used basic tutorial for setting up SharpGL in WPF, then instead of using SharpGL directly to render objects, I just wrapped the relative native code into a managed dll and called the object from there. Don't know if there will be performance issues, but I'm not looking to make anything graphically intensive.